# How to use a single shiny session after reloading?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am building a shiny application that will be used by multiple users on a Shiny Open Source Server. Here is a small reprex (from the documentation of `shiny`)

```
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      numericInput("n", "n", 1),
      plotOutput("plot")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$plot <- renderPlot( plot(head(cars, input$n)) )
    }
  )
```

After running the app, I set the `numericInput` to 10 and I close the browser. When I open the application again, a new session is started and the value in the `numericInput` is back at 1. How can I ensure that only one session is active and any user accessing the application, sees this session?

My application is quite large (seperated over several files and modules, with dynamic UI's), so it is not desirable, that every user has to go over all the input fields (>50) every time they start the App.

Comment: You realize that would mean having it open 24h every day, right?

Comment: Well, that is something that is exactly what I want to prevent. The session should remain active, even if the browser is closed.

Comment: You might want to give your users the possibility to save [bookmarks](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html) so they can restore a certain state of the application.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? Do you mind sharing how did you?

Comment: @Sam I solved it using a database in the backend, adding action buttons to save a certain input. After starting a new session, the values are retrieved from that database.